# The Execute method of job definition Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.FeedCacheRepopulationJob threw an exception

Tags: sharepoint-server, sharepoint-foundation, user-profile-service, distributedcache

We are getting below error in SharePoint 2019 server event viewer logs.

> The Execute method of job definition
>   Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.FeedCacheRepopulationJob (ID
>   7a18f297-7677-430d-9441-de12f658001a) threw an exception. More
>   information is included below.

Event ID: 6398

i have followed all the steps mentioned in below URL

https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/anneste/2016/09/23/event-id-6398-the-execute-method-of-job-definition-microsoft-office-server-userprofiles-lmtrepopulationjob-id-xxx-threw-an-exception/

Also i have restarted all the timer and SharePoint services and App pools in IIS. Still site is throwing error.
[image]

Please assist.

Comment: Where are you get this error?

Comment: Screenshot i have attached is the error we are getting in HTTPS while accessing the site. And the mentioned error we are getting in event viewer logs

Comment: Have you tried to browse your site with the server hostname inside the server?

Comment: @MohamedEl-QassasMVP  it is working fine when i am browsing from IIS directly

Comment: Have you configured Alternate access mapping?!

Comment: @MohamedEl-QassasMVP yes AAM is already there and it was working fine till yesterday.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the ULS log for more detailed information.

If there is any error message in the ULS log related to "No DNS entries exist for…", if so, verify that the DNS does not in fact exist and then add the appropriate DNS entry for the server.

Reference: [The Execute method of job definition Microsoft.Office.Server. UserProfiles .FeedCacheRepopulationJob threw an exception](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/52497.sharepoint-2016-troubleshooting-the-execute-method-of-job-definition-microsoft-office-server-userprofiles-feedcacherepopulationjob-threw-an-exception.aspx)

If the issue exists, try to remove and re-add the Distributed Cache Service:

```
Stop-SPDistributedCacheServiceInstance
Remove-SPDistributedCacheServiceInstance
Add-SPDistributedCacheServiceInstance
```

Comment: Can you please let me know that how to check and add DNS entry for the server?